# Best Indexing Technique for MS SQL Server database

Tags: asp.net, indexing, pymssql

I have 1 billion mobile number in my database, I want to perform bulk search through excel/csv upload, what is the best indexing techniques suitable for this.

I am using as.net application as front end for search data

Comment: One by one for start, is this takes too much time ? Do you have test it ? Then maybe you can make a temporary table and add your search numbers, and connect it with the table and get the view of it.

Comment: I know how to search, but in backend i want to make search fast, so it should not search every record rather direct(minimum iterations)

Comment: Do you have try it and is slow ?

Comment: yes it takes approx five minute to search from 1 billion record

Comment: Try this, add the search fields, into a table, and then create a view where you connect the second table with the first, and get the connected results.